How to pass this gate in a blade file?
I am using Laravel 11.
In a blade file, I have this directive :
@can('delete', $work)
@endcan

And in my workPolicy file, I have this function
public function delete(User $user, Work $work): bool
{
    Log::info('I delete a work');
}

my problem is that the $work variable in my blade file is not of type Work. And so the delete method is never called.
So I would like to be able to "parse" or something like that the $work variable before calling the @can directive.
How to do that ?
Of course if I add this,it works :
@php
$workPolicy = App\Models\Work::find($work->id)
@endphp
@can('delete', $workPolicy)

but it is one more request !

What is the value of $work?

$work is the result of a query : $query = DB::table('works')->and many many more conditions . Sure it is my problem I know. I'm looking for a way to avoid redoing a nth query in my blade just before calling the @can directive

why not use the Work model to query the table in the first place?

Hi Kris, thks for your comment. The pb is that the query is so complex that I prefered make a traditionnal query. But you re right, The pb is there.

If your delete logic depends on $work, than you must pass the variable. If you logic does not depend on $work, you can use following code in blade.
@can('delete', App\Models\Work::class)
    <!-- The current user can delete -->
@endcan

More information can be found here
